# Как добавить свойства заказа после оформления?

Tags: php, битрикс

пытаюсь обновить свойство заказа, но не записывается свойство, пробовал по разному объявить

1-й вариант:

```
use Bitrix\Main;
Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler(
        'sale', 'OnSaleOrderSaved', 'addOrderProperty'
);

function addOrderProperty($event)
{
        $order = $event->getParameter("ENTITY");
        $code  = 'PAY_LINK';
        $value = "https://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . "/pay.php?ORDER_ID=" . $order->getId();

        if (CModule::IncludeModule('sale')) {

            if ($prop = CSaleOrderProps::GetList([], ['CODE' => $code])->Fetch()) {

                return CSaleOrderPropsValue::Add([
                    'NAME'           => $prop['NAME'],
                    'CODE'           => $prop['CODE'],
                    'ORDER_PROPS_ID' => $prop['ID'],
                    'ORDER_ID'       => $order,
                    'VALUE'          => $value
                ]);
            }
        }
}
```

2-й вариант:

```
use Bitrix\Main;
Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler(
        'sale', 'OnSaleOrderSaved', 'PayLink'
);


function PayLink(Main\Event $event) {
    CModule::IncludeModule("sale");
    $order = $event->getParameter("ENTITY");
    $paymentIds = $order->getPaymentSystemId();
    $personTypeId = $order->getPersonTypeId();
    $propertyCollection = $order->getPropertyCollection();
    
    if ($paymentIds[0] == 10) {
        $orderPropertyId = ($personTypeId == 1) ? 55 : 56;
        $somePropValue = $propertyCollection->getItemByOrderPropertyId($orderPropertyId);
        var_dump($somePropValue);
        if (!$somePropValue) {
            CSaleOrderPropsValue::Add(array(
                'ORDER_ID' => $order->getId(),
                'ORDER_PROPS_ID' => $orderPropertyId,
                'NAME' => "Ссылка на оплату",
                'VALUE' => "https://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . "/pay.php?ORDER_ID=" . $order->getId(),
                'CODE' => "PAY_LINK",
            ));
        } else {
            $propValue = $somePropValue->getValue();
            var_dump($propValue);
            if (empty($propValue)) {
                $somePropValue->setValue("https://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . "/pay.php?ORDER_ID=" . $order->getId());
                $somePropValue->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как сделать чтобы работало?

Answer (score 2):

Что-то вы в своем коде то используете D7, то старые методы.. вот решение на чистом D7. Данные код, при сохранении заказа, проверяет есть ли свойство PAY_LINK и в зависимости от этого добавляет свойство, либо обновляет, если оно заполнено не так как надо. Другие проверки, типа физ.лицо или юр.лицо, уж сами добавьте.

```php
/* дополнение для /bitrix/php_interface/init.php */

$eventManager = \Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance();
$eventManager->addEventHandler(
    'sale',
    'OnSaleOrderSaved',
    'addOrderPropertyPayLink'
);

function addOrderPropertyPayLink(\Bitrix\Main\Event $event) {

    /** @var \Bitrix\Sale\Order $order */
    $order = $event->getParameter("ENTITY");

    $payLinkCode = 'PAY_LINK';
    $serverName = \Bitrix\Main\Context::getCurrent()->getServer()->getServerName();
    $payLinkValue = 'https://' . $serverName . "/pay.php?ORDER_ID=" . $order->getId();

    /** @var \Bitrix\Sale\PropertyValueCollection $propertyCollection */
    $propertyCollection = $order->getPropertyCollection();

    $property = null;
    if($propertyCollection->getItemByOrderPropertyCode($payLinkCode) === null) {
        $property = $propertyCollection->createItem(
            [
                'NAME' => 'Ссылка на оплату',
                'CODE' => $payLinkCode,
                'TYPE' => 'STRING',
            ]
        );
    } else {
        $property = $propertyCollection->getItemByOrderPropertyCode($payLinkCode);
    }

    if($property && $property->getValue() !== $payLinkValue) {
        $property->setField('VALUE', $payLinkValue);
        $order->save();
    }
}
```